# "The specified module could not be found" on SQLDriverConnect

Tags: windows, odbc

Getting the error when trying to connect to a DSN with SQLDriverConnect.
SQLGetDiagRec shows me the following:

> Specified driver could not be loaded due to system error 126: The
> specified module could not be found (, )
> I can't disclose the name of the driver, but I can say that it is correct the the dll path exists.

I looked inside the registry at ODBC.INI and ODBCINST.INI and everything seems to be in order.

Any more ideas where to look?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out that the problem was not with my DLL, but with missing dependencies.

To find out which DLLS were missing I used process monitor to see which other DLLs failed to load after my DLL was accessed.

Initially I also tries to use Dependency Walker to solve the mystery, but load time was very long in my case and then there was just too much info.